# Explicity describe the $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(J)$ generated by $J$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am trying to solve the following question:

Let $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4\}$, and let $J=\{\{1\}, \{2\}\}$. Describe explicity the $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(J)$ generated by $J$.

And I am wondering if the answer should be $\{\emptyset, \Omega, \{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}$ or if $\{3\}$ and {4} also should be included in the set? **My solution is the following**:

To describe explicity the $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(J)$ generated by $J$, we need to find all the subsets of $\Omega$ that must be included in it. The $\sigma$-algebra should satisfy the following properties:

$(1)$ It contains the empty set $\emptyset$ and the entire set $\Omega$, 
$(2)$ It contains all the sets in $J$ itself, which are {1} and {2}.

Now, we need to add more sets to make it a $\sigma$-algebra. To do this, we need to consider all possible combinations of elements from $\Omega$ that can be formed using unions, complements, and countable intersections. Therefore, we get the following:

$\{1\} \cup \{2\} = \{1,2\}$ 
$\{1\} \cap \{2\} = \{1,2\}$ 
$\Omega$ \ $\{1,2\} = \{3,4\}$ 
$\Omega$ \ $\emptyset = \Omega$

Hence, we get that $\sigma(J)=\{\emptyset, \Omega, \{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}$.

However, I saw another solution that mentioned that the $\sigma(J)$ set should consists of all possible subsets of the $\Omega$ including the empty set, individual singleton sets, the full set, and combinations of these. Hence, according to this $\{3\}$ and $\{4\}$ should be in $\sigma(J)$. But when I asked chatGPT it said that since $\{3\}$ and $\{4\}$ are not directly generated by J, they should not be in $\sigma$(J). What is the correct solution here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\{\emptyset, \Omega, \{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{1,3,4\},\{2,3,4\}\}$. Then $\sigma(J)=A$.

In addition to what you suggested, $\{1,3,4\}$ and $\{2,3,4\}$ are necessary because $\{1,3,4\}=\{1\} \cup \{3,4\}=\{2\}^C$ and same thing for $\{2,3,4\}$. It remains to show that $A$ is a sigma algebra. We see that $A$ is closed under complement and also closed under countable union (there are only a finite number of sets so this can be checked by just enumerating all possibilities).

Thus, since $\sigma(J)$ is defined as the smallest sigma algebra that contains $J$, and we have found a sigma algebra by adding only necessary elements, then $\sigma(J)=A$.

Answer (score 0):

There's a quick but systematic way to describe the $\sigma$-algebra (or, more generally, any algebra) generated by a finite family of sets $J$.

To do this, define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\Omega$ where $a\sim b$ if and only if $J$ does not "distinguish" them, i.e., for each $S\in J$, either $a,b\in S$ or $a,b\in \Omega\backslash S$.

It's not too hard to see that the members of $\sigma(J)$ are precisely the $\sim$ saturated subsets of $\Omega$, i.e., those subsets that consist of a union of equivalence classes (we prove this below).

In your case you can see that the equivalence classes of $\sim$ are $\{1\}$, $\{2\}$, and $\{3,4\}$, so you need only iterate through the $2^3$ possible unions of these, to get:
\begin{align*}
\sigma(J) & = \left\{ \{1\}, \{1,2\}, \{1,3,4\}, \Omega, \emptyset, \{2\}, \{3,4\}, \{2,3,4\}\right\}
\end{align*}

Here is the proof this method works:

#### Proof

Observe firstly that there are only finitely many (in fact at most $2^{|J|}$) equivalence classes for $\sim$, as an element's class is completely determined by which members of $J$ it lies in.

Next, we observe that each individual equivalence class $[a]$ must lie in $\sigma(J)$,  since
$$[a]=\left(\bigcap_{S\in J\text{, }a\in S} S\right) \cap \left(\bigcap_{S\in J \text{,} a\notin S} (\Omega\backslash S)\right)\text{,}$$
and then it follows by closure under (finite) unions that every $\sim$ saturated set lies in $\sigma(J)$.

Conversely, every member of $J$ is easily seen to be $\sim$ saturated, and since saturation is clearly preserved by complements and (arbitrary) unions, the saturated sets form a $\sigma$ algebra which must therefore contain $\sigma(J)$.

#### Remark

One might be tempted to try to extend this to the case that $J$ is countably infinite, but the proof breaks down because there are then potentially uncountably many equivalence classes, and  $\sigma(J)$ need not be closed under uncountable unions.